# unbound method get_sample_size() : when saving a wav file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyaudio

I am trying to save a wav file. 
data is an numpy array with data type of `int16`. 
When I run my code, it give me following error, which I don't understand.

```
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
TypeError: unbound method get_sample_size() must be called with PyAudio instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
Exception wave.Error: Error('sample width not specified',) in <bound method Wave_write.__del__ of <wave.Wave_write instance at 0x02B777D8>> ignored
```

My Code:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio
wf = wave.open(Config.WAVE_FORMATTED_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(Config.CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(Config.FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(Config.RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(data))
wf.close()
```

My Config

```
class Config():
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
WAVE_FORMATTED_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "new_output.wav"
```

The big picture is:

I extracted out data from the wav file. I am appending image bits at the end of a data array. Now saving the data in back in wav format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you meant:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

instead of

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio
```